# Wider to longer transformation in R

Tags: r, reshape, tidyr

Consider the following data with wider shape,

```
ID   OPEN   ANSWER   CLOSE   OPEN_BY   CLOSE_BY
1     13     15       17     ABC        XXYZ
```

I want to transform to longer shape using `tidyr::pivot_longer` as below.

```
ID   date     user
1     13       ABC
1     15       NA
1     17       XYZ
```

Thanks in advance.

**Reproducible Sample Data**

```
structure(list(ID = 1L, OPEN = 13L, ANSWER = 15L, CLOSE = 17L, 
    OPEN_BY = "ABC", CLOSE_BY = "XXYZ"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-1L))
```

Answer (score 1):

You perhaps need some transformation of names before proceeding

a demo example

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <-  read.table(header = T, text = 'ID   OPEN   ANSWER   CLOSE   OPEN_BY   CLOSE_BY
1     13     15       17     ABC        XXYZ')
names(df)[grep('_', names(df), invert = TRUE)] <- paste0(names(df)[grep('_', names(df), invert = TRUE)], '_x')

df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = !ID_x, names_pattern = '([^_]*)_(.*)', names_to = c('a','.value')) %>%
  select(-a)
#> # A tibble: 3 x 3
#>    ID_x     x BY   
#>   <int> <int> <chr>
#> 1     1    13 ABC  
#> 2     1    15 <NA> 
#> 3     1    17 XXYZ
```

---

or may be this one, (my [friend](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14314520/anoushiravan-r) suggested this) in one pipe

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <-  read.table(header = T, text = 'ID   OPEN   ANSWER   CLOSE   OPEN_BY   CLOSE_BY
1     13     15       17     ABC        XXYZ')

df %>%
  rename_with(~ paste0(., '_date'), !(ID | ends_with("BY"))) %>%
  pivot_longer(!ID, names_to = c("n", ".value"),
               names_pattern = "(.*)_(.*)") %>%
  select(-n)

#> # A tibble: 3 x 3
#>      ID  date BY   
#>   <int> <int> <chr>
#> 1     1    13 ABC  
#> 2     1    15 <NA> 
#> 3     1    17 XXYZ
```